# Connecting Two Django Apps, but Keeping them Separated

Tags: django, django-models

I have two distinct Django Apps, each one completely working separated. Those Apps are "PointOfSale" and "Inventory". What occurs is that both of these Apps have a "Product" table, in which the products are inserted. Now, keeping those two tables filled with basic the same data is obvious redundant (actually, the Inventory table of Products have more fields).

I'm now contemplating the different merge strategies to deal with this issue and I would like some help. Ideally, I would like to keep the possibility of each App working independently. So, I envisioned the following scenarios:

- A Save Signal that keep the two tables insync
- The connection of the two with OneToOne connection
- Generic Relationship
- The creation of a third App, called Products, in which the tables Products and CategoryOfProducts are kept, and both the Apps PointOfSale and Inventory uses it as a prerequisite.
- MErge everything in one big App.
- Another that I couldn't think of.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use the same database table from both Product models. See how you can have multiple databases in apps: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example

So say AppA uses DB_A and AppB uses DB_B as databases for their unique models and that Product model/table is in DB_A. You can configure AppB to use DB_A for Product model while keeping DB_B for other models.

Ideally, if the models are the same, you can package Product app so that the same code is used in all projects.